# Connect all slicers to all pivottables

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

every time I make a dashboard, I'm always clicking through the slicers and hiding empty data values as well as connecting them to all the pivottables on the sheet. I tried to automate that with the following vba code:

```
Sub sliceredits()
    Dim sc As SlicerCache
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    
    For Each sc In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches
        sc.CrossFilterType = xlSlicerCrossFilterHideButtonsWithNoData

        For Each pvt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
            sc.PivotTables.AddPivotTable (ActiveSheet.PivotTables(pvt))
        Next pvt
    Next myCache

End Sub
```

And get an error "Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class." Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Untested, but try `sc.PivotTabales.AddPivotTable pvt`.

Comment: Thanks! But that throws "Application-defined or object-defined error".